# SweetAlert2 - Only dismiss after confirming fucntion

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I am using `preConfirm` to only dismiss the popup if the input matches the value (a confirm UX). The problem is that if I enter an input that doesn't match and press remove, the buttons are disabled.

How do I set up the `preConfirm` so that the buttons aren't disabled after an incorrect entry?

```js
$(".admin__list").on("click", ".btn--remove", function(e) {
  var $btn = $(this);
  swal({
    title: "Remove User?",
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete and remove all permissions for this user?",
    confirmButtonText: "Remove",
    confirmButtonColor: "#f27474",
    cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    reverseButtons: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    html: ' <b class="sweet__code">1234</b>' +
      '<input type="text" class="sweet__input"></>' +
      '<dive class="sweet__error">Error!</>',
    preConfirm: function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var sweetCode = $(".sweet__code").html();
        if ($(".sweet__input").val() == sweetCode) {
          $btn.closest(".admin__item").remove();
          resolve();
        } else if ($(".sweet__input").val() !== sweetCode) {
          $(".sweet__error").show();
        }
      });
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {}
  });
});
```

```css
.sweet__error {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<div class="admin__list">
  <div class="admin__item">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--remove">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <div class="admin__item">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--remove">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sweetalert2 has a built in functionality for this. See [documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types).

Also, see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/563j1Lcp/).

```js
$(function() {

  const code = 1234;

  $(".admin__list").on("click", ".btn--remove", function(e) {
swal({
  title: "Remove User?",
  text: "Are you sure you want to delete and remove all permissions for this user?",
  confirmButtonText: "Remove",
  confirmButtonColor: "#f27474",
  cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
  reverseButtons: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  input: 'text',
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    if (!value || value != code) {
      return 'Invalid input!'
    }
  }
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    $(this).closest(".admin__item").remove();
    count();
  }
});
  });

})
```

```css
.sweet__error {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<div class="admin__list">
  <div class="admin__item">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--remove">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <div class="admin__item">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--remove">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue but forcing the buttons `swal.enableButtons();` if the input didn't match the code.

```
preConfirm: function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    var sweetCode = $(".sweet__code").html();
    if ($(".sweet__input").val() == sweetCode) {
      $btn.closest(".admin__item").remove();
      resolve();
    } else if ($(".sweet__input").val() !== sweetCode) {
      $(".sweet__error").addClass("active");
      swal.enableButtons();
    }
  });
}
```